# NSDate error using scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: Extra argument 'selector' in call

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer

I can't figure out for the life of me why Xcode is throwing the error "Extra argument 'selector' in call."  The method signature is fine and there is no extra 'selector' argument.  Also, the auto complete brings the method up but Option-clicking on scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval says "No Quick Help" and the font is black instead of purple as if the compiler is not recognizing it.  Here is the  code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!
    var timer = NSTimer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        stopButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func didPressStartButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector:Selector("updateTimeLabel"), userInfo: NSDate(), repeats: TRUE)

    }
    func updateTimerLabel() {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `true` instead of `TRUE`. `TRUE` is not defined in Swift, so the call does not compile. Swift errors are arcane - it often doesn't get the correct point of failure.

```
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector:Selector("updateTimeLabel"), userInfo: NSDate(), repeats: true)
```

works fine in Playground.

**Update**
It's probably worth pointing out, too, that the `Selector()` 'function' is redundant - the string name of the function - `"updateTimeLabel"` in this case - works equally well.

Comment: That worked!  I hate these totally unclear errors.  That took way more time to figure out than it was worth.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error when I had an invalid argument in the first parameter like this:

```
    var delayHighlight = 2
    var theDelay = fastPlay ? 0.0 : delayHighlight
    if playerRank > aiRank {
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(theDelay,target:self,selector:"showPlayerOutline",userInfo:nil,repeats:false)
    }
```

The problem was because the delayHighlight was being seen as an integer and therefore, the variable theDelay too was seen as an integer.  Change first line to:

```
var delayHighlight = 2.0
```

So, if this is not your problem I suggest looking at each parameter to see if it's the correct type.